# Vue 2 in-template type validation breaks with defineComponent without `data` property

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a project on Vue 2 with composition-api enabled as a dependency.

It turned out that when I use `defineComponent` syntax in SFCs and have `setup` instead of `data`, then type validation doesn't work inside the component's template. For example, if I have something like:

```
<ParentComponent>
  <MyComponent :message="true" :property="unknownVar" />
</ParentComponent>
```

and `MyComponent` expects a `string` for a `message` prop (not `boolean`), I don't have an error reported by IDE. Similarly, if `ParentCmponent` doesn't have a property `unknownVar`, I also don't have an error. When I hover over a `MyComponent` name in the template, I see that it's of the type `unknown`. Type detection works fine in the script. For example, when hovering on the component name inside `components` property, the type is recognised like this:

```
MyComponent: ComponentOptions<Vue, ShallowUnwrapRef<Data> & * ...
```

but it doesn't "get into" the template for some reason.

My IDE is VS Code with [TypeScript Vue Plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.vscode-typescript-vue-plugin) and [Volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Vue.volar) extensions enabled. My colleague using WebStorm (with it's own TS support tools) also don't see such errors.

But if I add a `data` property (which might be strange having it along with `setup`), even if it returns empty object, then in-template validation starts working highlighting the mentioned errors.

Another way to enable in-template errors is to use `Vue.extend` instead of `defineComponent` syntax (without `setup` then, of course).

I would appreciate very much if somebody could explain me what's going on. Is this behaviour normal or is there some way to tune it so that I wouldn't need `data` and `setup` in one component and at the same time enjoy type checking inside the template?

Here are some dependencies from the project:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.1",
  "vue": "^2.6.14",
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.18.0",
  "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.18.0",
  "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
  "typescript": "~4.6.3",
  "vue-template-compiler": "2.6.14",
}
```